# how to pythonically pass arguments to methods of subclassed widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I subclassed `Label` to automatically `.pack()` it:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        l = Label(parent, text="word")

root = tk.Tk()
App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to have the ability to pass arguments to `.pack()` when creating an instance of `Label`.

As it stands above, all `kwargs` are passed to the parent `tk.Label` so I cannot update my call as `l = Label(parent, text="word", side=tk.LEFT)` (with the idea of passing `**kwargs` to `.pack()`) - the program will crash because of unknown options to both `tk.Frame.__init__` (`side`) and `.pack()` (`text`).

The only idea I have to overcome this is to manually dispatch the arguments in `kwargs` to `tk.Frame.__init__` and to `.pack()` before calling them:

```
class Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        # __init__ parameters
        initparms = dict()
        for p in ['text']:
            if kwargs.get(p):
                initparms[p] = kwargs.get(p)
        # pack parameters
        packparms = dict()
        for p in ['side']:
            if kwargs.get(p):
                packparms[p] = kwargs.get(p)
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent, initparms)
        self.pack(packparms)
```

It works but is there a better (= pythonic) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using 'text', you don't actually need the list each time.  You can do:

```
if 'text' in kwargs:
    initparms['text'] = kwargs['text']
```

which makes things a bit better.

So if you want to do a whole bunch at a time:

```
for param in ['text', 'another', 'option']:
    if param in kwargs:
        initparms[param] = kwargs[param]
```

the extra `.get()` calls are not needed here.

Since Python 2.7, you can actually create your list in one go, using:

```
{key:value for key,value in ...}
```

syntax.  So:

```
initparms = {k:v for k,v in kwargs.items()
             if k in ['text','and','other','valid','params']}
```

However, this is a little ugly, and putting things like this in the middle of a function that does other stuff is a little unfriendly.

It's usually a good idea to separate things out to make functions smaller.

```
VALID_LABEL_OPTIONS=['text', 'and', 'so', 'on']
VALID_PACK_OPTIONS = ['side', 'etc']

def extract_args(all_args, valid_keys):
    return {k:v for k,v in all_args.items()
            if k in valid_keys}
```

and then in your `__init__` function you can do:

```
initparms = extract_args(kwargs, VALID_LABEL_OPTIONS)
packparms = extract_args(kwargs, VALID_PACK_OPTIONS)
```

which keeps each section of your logic separate.

Does this help?